# PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory does not split urls

Tags: solr, tokenize

I have a Solr instance where I index web pages, and I want to be able to query on parts of the url. E.g. `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page` should also match `en.wikipedia.org` by itself.

To do this, I have made a field called `url_tokens`, which gets copied over from my `url` field, and which gets analyzed using the `PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory` at index time.

I thought that the `url_tokens` field would contain `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`, `en.wikipedia.org/wiki` and `en.wikipedia.org`, but this is the result I get from the Solr admin query interface:

```
...
"url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page",
"url_tokens": [
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
],
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

These are the relevant parts of my schema.xml:

```
<field name="url_tokens" type="url_tokens_type" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<field name="url" type="url" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<copyField source="url" dest="url_tokens"/>

<fieldType name="url" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">                                                                                  
  <analyzer>                                                                                                   
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>                                                       
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>                                                            
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"/>                                                      
  </analyzer>                                                                                                  
</fieldType>           

<fieldType name="url_tokens_type" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Did you try query with part of the URL like `en.wikipedia.org`

Comment: @buddy86 Thanks, your comment made me think in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Things were working fine with my setup, it was just that I expected the wrong output.

I expected that since I had tokenized the field using the `PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory` and the field was multivalued, I would get a result of

```
"url_tokens": [
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki"
  "http://en.wikipedia.org"
],
```

But the reason I got

```
"url_tokens": [
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
],
```

in the search results was because the field was stored. The tokenization happens because the field was also indexed, but these tokens never show up in the search results, they are only used to select which results to show.

I had not previously used the [anaysis screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen) of the solr admin GUI, but I have used it to confirm that the urls are tokenized correctly.